# How To make string / database into a variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, variables

i hawe some problem here. i want make a string to be a variable,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users Where username = 'fahmi'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Result of the array is - `$result['data']="$a"`

```
$a = "This is a Result 1" ;
$b = "This is a Result 2" ;
$c = "This is a Result 3" ;

$final = $result['data'];
echo $final;
```

When i ran this code, result is `$a` but i want the result is `"This is a result 1"`, please help me, thanks...

Comment: looks like you might be wanting [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Just remove the double Quotation from `$a`, like: `$result['data'] = $a`, `$a` is a variable so you not needs to use those `"`,

Comment: @FrayneKonok from how i understand it `$a` is stored in the database and the asker wants this data field to determine which variable to use

Comment: If the OP just store the `a / b / c`, then it will be just variable of variables. Ex: `$final = $$result['data'];`, and then echo `$final`.

Comment: Every-one above is correct, but in your case no mean, because `$result` actually have data from db in array format and you are over-writing this array with your `$a,$b,$c` variables. and from where they come from and what they mean here is not clear too.

Comment: Is $a declared before it's assigned to $result['data'] ? PHP should throw a notice for Undefined variable if it is.  @Anant is correct, you should iterate over the $result variable since it's type is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want variable variables the you can achieve it this way:

```
$$a = "This is a Result 1" ;
$$b = "This is a Result 2" ;
$$c = "This is a Result 3" ;
```